# Mono CubieBoard2 Cubian (Debian Port) armhf GTK#

Tags: .net, git, exception, mono, gtk#

Loving the CubieBoard2 A20 lots of power, great board for the price. Cubian is a nice port of Debian. Downloaded Mono from GIT and compiled OK. Tried to run some code with the following error.

Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'gtk-sharp, Version=2.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'gtk-sharp, Version=2.8.0.0, Culture=neutral
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'gtk-sharp, Version=2.8.0.0, Culture=neutral

I am no genius here, any assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My Bad, thought GTK was part of Mono Package. Installed and built GTK as follows..

1. git clone -b gtk-sharp-2-12-branch https://github.com/mono/gtk-sharp.git
2. cd gtk-sharp
3. ./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr/local
4. make
5. make install

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

==
sudo echo "deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian sid main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mono-complete -t sid

(http://www.forum-cubieboard.de/Thread-mono-on-cubietruck-cubian)